# Error Migrating Google Workspace to O365 - Calendar API Errors

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to build out a migration from Google Workspace into MS365. I've tried each of MS's recommended methods; Automatic, Manual, and PowerShell. For each one, I get the same error message

> post-migration
> uri=https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?maxResults=250 response={ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Google Calendar API has not been used in project 206754733531 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar-json.googleapis.com/overview?project=206754733531 then retry.

If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",

> "errors": [ { "message": "Google Calendar API has not been used in project 206754733531 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar-json.googleapis.com/overview?project=206754733531 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.", "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "accessNotConfigured", "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help", "links": [ { "description": "Google developers console API activation", "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar-json.googleapis.com/overview?project=206754733531" } ] }, { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": { "consumer": "projects/206754733531", "service": "calendar-json.googleapis.com" } } ] } } . --> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

When I follow the link

```
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar-json.googleapis.com/overview?project=206754733531**
```

I see the following screen

[image: Calendar API Enabled]

Relating to the PERMISSION_DENIED portion of the error, I have ensured that the ServiceAccount associated with the project has been added to the project and has the requisite permissions based on MS's documentation.

I really don't know what I'm doing incorrectly or where I'm going wrong. I'm incredibly new to all things programming and development so I apologize if this isn't nearly enough detail. I'm happy to provide more context/info as needed.

Comment: Can i see the code you are using for powershell just curious really.  I have never seen anyone get service account working with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

> Google Calendar API has not been used in project 206754733531 before or it is disabled

Means that the Google calendar api has not been enabled in your app or its disabled.

Here are a few things to check in order of likelihood of causing your issue.

I would double check that you are in fact checking the correct project on google developer console for the service account credentials you are using.  You may have downloaded a file for a different project and are checking the wrong one.

After that i would check the quota allotment you have for the google calendar api.  Click the manage button in that link.  If your quota is 0 then google has disabled your access for some reason.  If they have check your email they should have told you why it was disabled.

> SERVICE_DISABLED

If you have created the service account on google developer console logged in as a standard gmail user its not going to work.   Service accounts only work with google calendar api with google workspace.

> PERMISSION_DENIED

Make sure that you are creating this service account on the domain that you intended to access.  Google calendar only works with service accounts from google workspace domain accounts with domain wide delegation setup.     Great guide in setting up delegation [Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) just change the scopes to the google calendar scope you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I created the GCP Project using the `Automate the configuration of your Google Workspace for migration` option in the Exchange Admin Center. However, even though the UI claimed that it added the Calendar, Contacts, and Gmail API to the Project. However, this was not the case.

I needed to add the Calendar and Contacts APIs manually. Then it worked like a charm.

Comment: Can you please share the steps?

Comment: You need to go to the GCP project you created (or that Microsoft created for you). Then go to the marketplace and type: "Contacts API" and click on "Enable". Then you need to do the same for the "Google Calendar API" and the "Gmail API". Once these are enabled you should be able to complete the migration from Google to Microsoft. Good luck!